# How to GET data from API

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, get

My API URL contains a payment transaction ID. I want to GET the data about this transaction from my API. The part that says `console.log(response);` is where I need to GET the data from the API. I will then fill this data into labels. How can I do this? I am using jQuery, ASP.NET, and C#. Thanks.

```
    $.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
```

Comment: Well I guess you are already doing it. The `response` variable is the result that you have received from the server and should include your payment transaction ID.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Sorry for the confusion. I do see the output when I look at the Console. However I want to break out the fields individually. The object contains fields like transaction_id, organization_id, location_id, status, and more.

Comment: Have a look at this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: Is the `response` value an object or a string with JavaScript Object Notation (JSON)?

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)).  By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 1):

Adding 'success' and 'error' methods to the ajax call will help fetch the data and error codes.

Here is a working example:

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json",
    url: "URL_WITH_TRANSACTION_ID",

    headers: {
              "Authorization": "auth-header-string"
            },
    success: function (output) {
        console.log("Success: " + JSON.stringify(output))
    },
    error: function (e) {
        console.log("ERROR : ", e.responseText)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe native fetch is better choice? Just suggestion.

```
const { transaction_id } = await fetch(settings).then(r => r.json())
```

Answer (score 0):

Tell the `$.ajax` function to expect a `JSON` response. Do this by adding `"datatype": "json"` to the settings object. This now means that the response you receive will be treated as `JSON`, meaning if it is a string with an object in it, it will turn the string into a workable object for you.

From the [jQuery documentation:](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

> dataType: The type of data that you're expecting back from the server. If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response (an XML MIME type will yield XML, in 1.4 JSON will yield a JavaScript object, in 1.4 script will execute the script, and anything else will be returned as a string).

```
function SubmitTransaction() {

    // Card Card US Transaction Settings and Data
    var settings = {
        "url": "URL_WITH_TRANSACTION_ID",
        "method": "GET",
        "dataType": "json", // Add this line.
        "headers": {
            "X-Forte-Auth-Organization-Id": "ORGID",
            "Authorization": "AUTHID",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },

    }

    $.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {
        console.log(response.transaction_id);
        console.log(response.organization_id);
        console.log(response.location_id);
        console.log(response.status);
        // etc..
    });
}
```